# Using multiple IF statements in the same cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I would like a column that displays ISLA, OSLA or N/A which I can then use to create a %age figure against the amount of ISLA entries compared to OSLA based on the data.

I'm not that great at excel and there might be a better way of doing this whole task but I have tried to achieve this with the IF command. It checks if C is "available", then checks if it's a Sunday and compares the Time Converted to the relevant SLA figure - where 06:00 is a weekday and 08:00 is a Sunday. Excel has finally accepted the statement's formatting but it's got the #NAME? error.

My Table currently looks like this;

[image]

My IF statement is this;

=IF(C2 = "Available",IF(E2 = "Sunday", IF(D2 > F3, “OSLA”, ”ISLA”), IF(D2 > F2, “OSLA”, “ISLA”)), “N/A”)

The cells in D have this formula; =--TEXT(B23,"00:00:00")

The insert function on the statement looks like this;

[image]

Comment: It seems the quote marks you have around “OSLA”, ”ISLA” are not the accepted delimiters for Excel. You can see they look different to those around "Sunday" for example. Try deleting those and replacing them.

Comment: That has fixed it, thank you very much. I had pasted it into word previously for the colour formatting so I could clearly see what was where - I guess word changed the quote formatting.

The #NAME error has now gone but the results are wrong.

For example, it states that Row 5 is OSLA - when 03:43:27 is less than 06:00:00.

Comment: Please disregard that, it's because I've dragged the formula down and it has incremented the H* references.

I'll just remove the reference to H* and put the actualy time in, instead as the first row works.

Comment: @Dave this is working now, your suggestion was the resolution but because it's a comment I can't mark it as an answer.

FYI - the finished formula is; 
`=IF(C56 = "Available",IF(E56 = "Sunday", IF(D56 > TIME(8,0,0), "OSLA", "ISLA"), IF(D56 > TIME(6,0,0), "OSLA", "ISLA")), "N/A")`

I then use count if to count OSLA/ISLA, total them up and work out the percentage from there.

Comment: Now added as answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the quote marks you have around “OSLA”, ”ISLA” are not the accepted delimiters for Excel. You can see they look different to those around "Sunday" for example. Just delete those and replace them.